# Getting an error while including cruton library

Tags: android, crouton

I am using cruton library as the option of the toast message in android studio.

I have included the code as per the readme on the https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton link. But I am continuously getting error plugin as **android:id=maven** is not found.

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.firstclicker.bengaliclicker"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/crouton-1.8.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar') {
        // exclusion is not necessary, but generally a good idea.
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }

}
```

The dependencies are inserted in the build.gradle file. Even though the error persists which is "Error(17,0) Plugin with id 'android-maven' not found

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use maven. Use `gradle`instead.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  ...
  compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar') {
    // exclusion is not necessary, but generally a good idea.
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have included dependencies now eventhough I am facing same issue. Please look at my updated question please..

Comment: Remove `compile files('libs/crouton-1.8.2.jar')` from gradle and remove that lib from `libs` file.